# UnknownError sending messages to Teams

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to send a message into a channel inside an organization's Teams.
I have deployed the app successfully, and I get an Authentication token.
When I do as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta) to send messages to a chat, via C# as follows:

```
 _token = await _authenticationHelper.GetAuthenticationToken();
 AccessToken = _token;
 string teamId = "xxx-xxx-xxx-XX-Xxxxx";
 string channelId = "...thread.skype";

 var val = await HttpPost($"/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages", 
                "{ \"body\": { \"contentType\": \"html\", \"content\": \"Hello World\" } }",  endpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");
```

get an error from Microsoft Graph Stating:

```
System.Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "44b6397d-aae4-4f60-a2fd-200070c64908",
      "date": "2019-04-18T12:30:02"
    }
  }
}
```

This error is not descriptive so I don't really know what went wrong.

Comment: Are you using delegated permissions for this request?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT You mean in the app permisions at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com ? There I've set both Applications Permissions and Delegated Permissions.

Comment: Only delegated permissions are supported for sending a message to the channel. Could you please confirm if you are using [token generated on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-beta)?

Comment: Thankyou. @Wajeed-MSFT

Comment: I have the same issue and I believe I'm asking for the correct token:
  Data:='client_id='+ClientID+
        '&scope='+GetAccessScopes+
        '&client_secret='+ClientSecret+
        '&grant_type=authorization_code'+
        '&code='+AuthCode+
        '&redirect_uri='+CallbackURL+
'&scope=offline_access Group.ReadWrite.All';